# Sort a given array whose elements range from 1 to n , in which one element is missing and one is repeated

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have to sort this array in O(n) time and O(1) space.

I know how to sort an array in O(n) but that doesn't work with missing and repeated numbers. If I find the repeated and missing numbers first (It can be done in O(n)) and then sort , that seems costly.

```
static void sort(int[] arr)
{
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(i>=arr.length)
            break;
        if(arr[i]-1 == i)
            continue;
        else
        {
        while(arr[i]-1 != i)
        {
            int temp = arr[arr[i]-1];
            arr[arr[i]-1] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try find the missing number or the repeated number. Once you do that, you can easily sort the array. There are O(n) methods to find a duplicate in an array

Comment: yeah I know that but can't we do it in one traversal , without finding those elements ?

Comment: Yes, finding the missing and the repeated elements in O(n) is exactly the problem you need to solve. Perhaps if you can figure out which of the two is larger it will be a bit easier to find them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void sort() {
  for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
    while (a[i] != a[a[i]]) {
      std::swap(a[i], a[a[i]]);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
    if (a[i] == i) continue;
    for (int j = a[i] - 1; j >= i; --j) a[j] = j + 1;
    for (int j = a[i] + 1; j <= i; ++j) a[j] = j - 1;
    break;
  }
}
```

Explanation: 
Let's denote m the missing number and d the duplicated number

- Please note in the `while` loop, the break condition is `a[i] != a[a[i]]` which covers both `a[i] == i` and `a[i]` is a duplicate.
- After the first for, every non-duplicate number `i` is encountered 1-2 time and moved into the `i-th` position of the array at most 1 time.
- The first-found number d is moved to d-th position, at most 1 time
- The second d is moved around at most N-1 times and ends up in m-th position because every other i-th slot is occupied by number i
- The `second outer for` locate the first i where a[i] != i. The only i satisfies that is `i = m`
- The 2 `inner fors` handle 2 cases where `m < d` and `m > d` respectively

Full implementation at http://ideone.com/VDuLka

Comment: please elaborate the last two for loops . I can't understand.

Comment: You have m (= i inside the 2nd for) and d (= a[i]) and only have to fill in the numbers in that range, m -> d or d -> m.  What would you do?

Comment: It gives wrong result. please check for input 4,2,2,3,1

Comment: Yes it did. Turn out inner `for`s from a[i] - 1 and a[i] + 1 (instead of -2 and +2) are neccessary. I was over confident as it passed 1000 random-generated tests. Edited the code. And make sure you store the elements in a[1]..a[N], i.e leaving a[0] unused in zero-based arrays

Comment: Actually I got it right with my first version. But then I tried replacing +1/-1 by +2/-2, the tests passed, and I posted it without further checking or reasoning. But my check() function was incorrect :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find missing and repeated numbers. You do this by solving following system of equations:

[image: equation]

Left sums are computed simultaneously by making one pass over array. Right sums are even simpler -- you may use formulas for arithmetic progression to avoid looping. So, now you have system of two equations with two unknowns: missing number `m` and repeated number `r`. Solve it.

Next, you "sort" array by filling it with numbers 1 to n left to right, omitting `m` and duplicating `r`. Thus, overall algorithm requires only two passes over array.

Comment: Right side sum of second equation = 1/3 n^3 + 1/2 n^2 + 1/6 n, which will overflow 32 bit unsigned integer for n >= 1626.

Comment: @rcgldr It's a matter of choosing types for the task, not algorithms. Nice to mention that, though.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
            int temp = arr[arr[i]-1];
```

add a check for duplicate in the loop:

```
            if((temp-1) == i){  // found duplicate
                ...
            } else {
                arr[arr[i]-1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }
```

See if you can figure out the rest of the code.

Comment: why would temp-1 be equal to i in case of duplicates ?

Comment: @rishavbansal - The problem uses the numbers 1 to n, the indices are 0 to n-1, this means after the numbers are in the correct location, arr[i] = i+1. Since temp = arr[...], then the check could be for temp == (i+1) or for (temp -1) == i. Since you already had a check for (arr[i]-1) != i, I chose to follow a similar check.